# Converting Text to Date in SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm reading data from fixed length text file with the code below

```
DATE                            SYSDATE,
NAME                            position(9:38),
SCORE                           position(39,41)
```

Now I want to load text as DATE directly. Examples are referring input from csv files only. Please help on this. Input can be empty string too in that case I'd like to replace it with SYSDATE.

Sample File content

```
11112016SachinTendulkar               110
12122016SachinTendulkar               101
        RahulDravid                   120
```

Date format in input will be DDMMYYYY

Comment: ?? Is there a "secret code" behind your question, and only the initiated need answer? WHAT text do you have in the file? What does it look like? I assume you are not trying to convert the string "position(30:40)" to a date, are you? If not, what ARE you trying to convert to a date?

Comment: Nothing is secret @mathguy , I'll add more details. Thanks for asking more info

Comment: So, the date is in positions 1-8 in each new line? You said the date may also be "null" in which case you want to enter SYSDATE (you probably mean without a time-of-day, so in fact TRUNC(SYSDATE)); what does that look like in the input file? Specifically, will the name in that case begin in position 1, or still in position 9? (Presumably still in position 9, otherwise this is not a "fixed length" text file, but ... just making sure.)

Comment: @mathguy Yes first 8 char will be date input in case date is not given all the 8 char will be spaces.

Comment: I deleted my answer - I missed the "SQL Loader" tag (also in the title!). It should be possible to convert directly from text to a date, just like it would be done with CSV. The fact that your file is fixed-width as opposed to CSV is an unrelated, different issue compared to "converting from text to date in the process of loading the data."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call your date column something more descriptive besides "date" as that is an Oracle reserved word.  I'll call it load_date.  Your control file entry then would look like this.  Use the NVL2 function.  If load_date is not null, convert it to a date.  If it is null, use sysdate.

```
load_date position(1:8) "nvl2(:load_date, to_date(:load_date, 'ddmmyyyy'), trunc(sysdate))"
```